# no mostrar parametros en la url metodo get laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Actualmente se muestra la url de la siguiente manera HOST.COM/blog/6 no trabajo con Models por eso no puedo realizarlo con slug, y el proyecto es grande y estoy a fecha de entrega, entonces mi pregunta es hay alguna manera de esconder los parametros sin usar Modelos ? Gracias:
mi consulta:

```
$query = DB::select('select * from users_cn where email = ? and pass = ?', [$request['correo'],$passEncoded]);
```

ruta en web.php

```
Route::get('/delete-user/{id}', [UserController::class,'deleteUser']);
```

Comment: Existen enfoques para esto que buscas lograr, ¿nos muestras que has intentado al momento?

Comment: Use y as en la ruta... modificar mi htaccess pero realmente no carezco de un buen entendiemiento de este tipo de archivo lo que me he encontrado en la web e ido poniendo pero nada me ha dado resultado.... llamar la url por el name pero para get tampoco como que funciona.

Comment: También el uso de el slug en Lara el pero no estoy trabajando con modelos entonces he buscado en la web acerca de esto pero parece que trabaja solo con los modelos.

Comment: Entonces lo que buscas es que el id como tal sea un valor que no quede directo en la url no?

Comment: Si tú sabes de alguno y me puedas brindar solo el nombre yo ya lo investigaré para ver si es de utilidad. Gracias.

Comment: Si ósea que solo me quede por ejemplo host.con/read-post